Getting ERROR: D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H When Adding adapty_flutter Dependency in Flutter
I’m encountering an error when trying to add the adapty_flutter package in my Flutter project. When I add adapty_flutter: ^2.10.3 and adapty_ui_flutter: ^2.1.3 to pubspec.yaml, I receive the following error during the build:
ERROR: D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
The error prevents the project from launching, and I’m looking for solutions to fix this issue. I’ve tried several troubleshooting steps, including adjusting my Kotlin and Gradle versions, but I haven’t had any success.
Project Details
build.gradle (Project-level)
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gradle (App-level)
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutter.versionCode
        versionName flutter.versionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // signing configs
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3")
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
}

pubspec.yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.5.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  adapty_flutter: ^2.10.3
  adapty_ui_flutter: ^2.1.3

Steps I’ve Tried
1) Kotlin and Gradle Versions: Tried changing the Kotlin version to 1.8.0 and 1.7.10, but the error persists.
2) MultiDex Enabled: Confirmed multiDexEnabled true in the build.gradle file and added androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1 dependency.
3) Cleaning and Rebuilding Project: Used flutter clean and reinstalled dependencies without success.
Additionally, I have another Flutter project with similar dependencies and configuration where adapty_flutter works without issues. This error only appears in my second project.
Question, What could be causing the D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H error, and how can I resolve it to successfully build and run my Flutter project with adapty_flutter?
Any advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

did you find any solutuon for this?
